# Uniqueness for homogeneous first order ODE with noncontinuous coefficient?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ satisfies $$f'(x)=a(x)f(x),$$
where $a(x)$ is only assumed to be a function defined pointwise on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Obviously the problem is ill-defined, since the regularity condition $f\in C^\infty$ will force some regularity condition on $a(x)$. At least at the point $x$ where $f(x)\neq 0$, we will get $$\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)=a(x),$$ so $a\in C^\infty(N_x)$ with $N_x$ being some open neighborhood of $x$.

Now, we suppose $f(0)=0$. Can we deduce that $f(x)\equiv 0$, without assuming any integrability on $a$? Or there is any counterexample?

Edit: As SassatelliGiulio pointed out, $f(x)=e^{-x^{-2}}$ is a nice non-analytic counterexample. If we give more restrictive condition on $f$, say its Taylor expansion matches with itself in the neighborhood of zero, can we conclude $f\equiv 0$ in a neighborhood of zero?

Edit2: $f(x)=x^2$ with $a(x)=2/x$ with $x>0$ and $a(0)=0$ is a counterexample. Finally, I would like to know if it is possible to deduce that $f\equiv 0$ with more restriction that $f(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0$, with $f$ being analytic.

Comment: There's $f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-x^{-2}}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$, with $a(x)=\begin{cases}2x^{-3}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Right, this is nice, thanks! Slightly more restrictive condition on $f$, what if $f$ is analytic (or at least matches with its Taylor series in the neighborhood of zero)? In these cases I expect $f\equiv 0$ in the neighborhood of zero, what do you think?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If $a(x)$ is only set to be in $L^p$ then it is not defined pointwise.

Comment: Take any differentiable function $f$ such that $f'(c)=0$ whenever $f(c)=0$. Then by setting $a(x)=\begin{cases}f'(x)/f(x)&\text{if }f(x)\ne 0\\ 5&\text{if }f(x)=0\end{cases}$ the condition $f'=af$ is satisfied automatically. It's clear that there are all sorts of non-zero functions like this. For instance, $x^2(x^2+1)^{-2}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio This is great, indeed $x^2(x^2+1)^{-2}$ satisfies all the criteria but still nontrivial. This somehow suggests that the uniform bound on $a$ is a crucial for the uniqueness of this ODE. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That's the convention for analysts and there's not much importance to discuss further on this.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank Sassatelli Giulio for the nice answer. Further to that, it is still impossible to conclude $f\equiv 0$ in a neighborhood of zero even with more restrictive condition mentioned in the edit.

Counterexample: $f(x)=x^2$ and $a(x)=2/x$ with $x>0$, and $a(0)=0$. Then the ODE $a(x)f(x)=f'(x)$ holds pointwise everywhere on $[0,\infty)$.

Finally, I would like to know if it is possible to deduce that
$f\equiv 0$ with more restriction that $f(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$, with $f$ being analytic.